# Page Arguments Not Getting Passed

Tags: commerce, routes

My code was working perfectly, but at some point my hook_menu page arguments stopped getting passed.

I am using versioning and can revert back to the previous code, but the page arguments are still broken.

Is there some change that could be causing page arguments to not get passed?

Thanks a million!

Disclaimer:  Sorry, I am not a Drupal developer, so the code is an attempt at injecting plain php into a site.

Inventory.module

```
    function inventory_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/commerce/inventory'] = array(
    'title' => 'Inventory',
    'description' => 'View inventory reports for your store.',
    'access arguments' => array('access commerce reports'), // Inherited by children.
    'page callback' => 'inventory_reports_dashboard',
    'page arguments' => array( '10', 'DESC', 'false', 'admin@sltwtr.com', 'false'),     // page_arguments = threshold amount,  sort direction, hide zero inventory, email report to, save_to_email bool, download_csv
    'file' => 'inventory.dashboard.inc',
    'weight' => 0,
  );

  $items['admin/commerce/inventory-download-csv'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'inventory_download_csv',
    'access arguments' => array('access commerce reports'),
    'file' => 'inventory.dashboard.inc',
    //'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );


  return $items;
}
```

Inventory.dashboard.inc

```
/**
 * Renders the inventory reports.
 */
function inventory_reports_dashboard( $threshold='10', $sort_direction='DESC', $hide_zero_inventory='false', $email='admin@sltwtr.com', $save_to_email = 'false') {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'commerce_reports') . '/theme/js/dashboard.js', 'file');
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'commerce_reports') . '/theme/css/commerce_reports_dashboard.css');

  // on first load we want to grab all of the default values
  // after first load, we want updated values to pass through
  //$threshold = 18;
  $render = file_get_contents('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/sites/all/modules/inventory/inventory.php?threshold=$threshold&sort_direction=$sort_direction&hide_zero_inventory=$hide_zero_inventory&email=$email&save_to_email=$save_to_email");

  return $render;
}



function inventory_download_csv(){
  $file = './inventory.csv';
  $filename = 'inventory.csv';
  //drupal_set_header('Content-Type: text/csv');
  //drupal_set_header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type: text/csv');
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
  if($file) {
    //file_transfer($file, array('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$filename));
    $csv_contents = file_get_contents('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/sites/all/modules/inventory/inventory.csv");
  }
  else {
    return drupal_access_denied();
  }
  $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
  //$csv_text = array2csv($db_result);
  fputs($fp, $csv_contents);
  fclose($fp);
  exit();

}
```

Inventory.php

```
<?php

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/myfunctionlib/myfunctionlib.module';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';

//require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/common.inc';
//require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/module.inc';
//require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/unicode.inc';
//require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/file.inc';

//drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);
clean_dump($_GET);
```

When I change the url:

mysite.gotpantheon.com/admin/commerce/inventory/12/DESC/false/admin@sltwtr.com

The get parameters no longer reflect changes

```
array(6) {
  ["threshold"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["sort_direction"]=>
  string(4) "DESC"
  ["hide_zero_inventory"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["email"]=>
  string(16) "admin@sltwtr.com"
  ["save_to_email"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["q"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Try passing your arguments like this: 'page arguments' => array( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4),

Comment: @Jance Yes, I add or remove a module to clear the cache.  But, I meant I just changed one of the url segments in the browser.

Comment: Nice suggestion J Reynolds. Are those not the defaults?  'page arguments' => array( '10', 'DESC', 'false', 'admin@sltwtr.com', 'false')

What do these numbers represent?  'page arguments' => array( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4),

Comment: @Bryan I don't think `page arguments` is doing something here, you can simple remove it, your callback function's args will work.. Dont forget to clear the cache.

Comment: I made a mistake. You already have three fragments in your url. It must be :  'page arguments' => array( 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),     and you should define your menu as  $items['admin/commerce/inventory/%/%/%/%/%']

Comment: @J.Reynold That sounds correct.  I didn't realize that they were the url segments.   I don't think I should change my definition. I define my menu with % placeholders, those segments are no longer optional, right?

Comment: No they are not. In that case just leave 'page arguments' out of the menu definition and pick up the arguments in your callback.

Comment: I could, but just changing to 'page arguments' => array( 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) works perfectly!  Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your code to (as @J.Reynolds specified):

```
  $items['admin/commerce/inventory/%/%/%/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Inventory',
    'description' => 'View inventory reports for your store.',
    'access arguments' => array('access commerce reports'), // Inherited by children.
    'page callback' => 'inventory_reports_dashboard',
    'page arguments' => array(3,4,5,6),     // page_arguments = threshold amount,  sort direction, hide zero inventory, email report to, save_to_email bool, download_csv
    'file' => 'inventory.dashboard.inc',
    'weight' => 0,
  );
```

Comment: The admin/commerce/inventory/%/%/%/% placeholder % don't seem necessary.  Mode code will provide default values.  Or maybe not.  But I'd like admin/commerce/inventory/ to use defaults.